# Why unique_values_df = df.selectExpr("distinct(DEST_COUNTRY_NAME)") is not working in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Why `unique_values_df = df.selectExpr("distinct(DEST_COUNTRY_NAME)")` is not working in `PySpark`?

For example, these work:

```
df.selectExpr("count(distinct(DEST_COUNTRY_NAME))")

df.select("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME").distinct()
```

but this does not:

```
df.selectExpr("distinct(DEST_COUNTRY_NAME)")
```

Although I have searched documents, I didn't find the solution.

Error:

```
AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_ROUTINE] Cannot resolve function `distinct` on search path [`system`.`builtin`, `system`.`session`, `spark_catalog`.`default`].; line 1 pos 1
```

Comment: distinct function is not present on  column: 
You can check list of builtin functions here - `https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html`

Comment: I appreciate your answer!
I understood dataframe.selectExpr method totally, thanks to @MohanaBC